Are magnetization induced by external $B$ field considered as "ordering"?
In ferromagnets, thermal fluctuation destroys ordering, which leads to no magnetization above Curie temperature.
Now, suppose we apply an external magnetic field $H$ above the Curie temperature, and force a magnetization to occur. In this case, the symmetry is not spontaneously broken, but as the fluctuation is suppreseed, do spins still have long-range order? Do spin waves still exist?
